# Need to Calculate few metrics from dataset using SQL - separate queries

Tags: mysql

Dataset looks like this : This is a sample dataset for number of employee login activity named - activity

I need to calculate few metrics, was able to do in python data frames, but new in mySQL.

1. what is the average number of employee active per day for month of jan 2018 by dept ( was able to do somewhat half of it, but results coming are not correct.
2. number of unique active employee (login >0) per month for jan 2018 for each dept_id (was able to do it)
3. month over month growth  for all dept_id from dec-2017 to jan 2018 where at least one employee was active (login >0) - no idea how to do this in sql
4. fraction of users who were active in each dept_id for dec 2017 and were also active in the same dept_id for jan 2018
5. how many employee login in on 3 or more consecutive days in jan 2018

Any help would be appreciated.

Query written for case 1:

```
select dept_id, 
    DAU 
from
(
    select dept_id
        , month(date)
        , year(date)
        , avg(logins) as DAU
    from
    (select * from activity where login >0)
    where year(date) =2018 
        and month(date) =1
    group by dept_id, month(date), year(date)
)
```

Textual Format Dataset

```
date    dept_id emp_id  logins
29-11-2017  ABC001  A1  1
30-11-2017  ABC002  A2  2
01-12-2017  XYZ001  A3  0
01-12-2017  XYZ002  A4  1
03-12-2017  ABC001  D2  4
04-12-2017  ABC002  D1  1
05-12-2017  XYZ001  A6  2
05-12-2017  XYZ002  A7  3
30-12-2017  ABC001  A8  0
01-01-2018  ABC002  A2  6
02-01-2018  XYZ001  A10 4
03-01-2018  XYZ002  A11 2
04-01-2018  ABC001  A1  2
04-01-2018  ABC002  A2  0
05-01-2018  XYZ001  A13 4
05-01-2018  XYZ001  A6  2
05-01-2018  XYZ002  A7  1
06-01-2018  XYZ001  A6  2
06-01-2018  XYZ002  A7  3
07-01-2018  XYZ001  A6  3
07-01-2018  XYZ002  A7  4
06-01-2018  XYZ002  A14 3
30-01-2018  ABC001  A15 2
```

Comment: I would love to help if you post the datasets in _textual form_ instead of as image.. I'm _too lazy_ to re-type the datasets in attempt to re-create your condition. It'll be much easier if I can just _copy and paste_ the whole datasets.

Comment: date dept_id emp_id logins
29-11-2017 ABC001 A1 1
30-11-2017 ABC002 A2 2
01-12-2017 XYZ001 A3 0
01-12-2017 XYZ002 A4 1
03-12-2017 ABC001 D2 4
04-12-2017 ABC002 D1 1
05-12-2017 XYZ001 A6 2
05-12-2017 XYZ002 A7 3
30-12-2017 ABC001 A8 0
01-01-2018 ABC002 A2 6
02-01-2018 XYZ001 A10 4
03-01-2018 XYZ002 A11 2
04-01-2018 ABC001 A1 2
04-01-2018 ABC002 A2 0
05-01-2018 XYZ001 A13 4
05-01-2018 XYZ001 A6 2
05-01-2018 XYZ002 A7 1
06-01-2018 XYZ001 A6 2
06-01-2018 XYZ002 A7 3
07-01-2018 XYZ001 A6 3
07-01-2018 XYZ002 A7 4
06-01-2018 XYZ002 A14 3
30-01-2018 ABC001 A15 2

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10910692/fano-fn ,here you go

Comment: Thanks, one more thing.. I notice the date value is non-standard format of `YYYY-MM-DD` .. is that how it really is in your table? Maybe you can add your table schema info, just run `SHOW CREATE TABLE activity;` then put the result into your question.

Comment: Also your query have defined an `account_id` column but it's not in your table example

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10910692/fano-fn this a CSV extract , however the data in SQL table will be in standard format as it's being pushed through spark and converted to standard format, you can consider dates to be in a standard format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10910692/fano-fn. Dept_id - varchar , emp_id - varchar, login - int

Comment: Never depend on the internal format of the date. In oracle, date is stored in bytes and it's good practice to convert the date in your desired format for displaying purpose or manipulation but never depend on the default format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this works otherwise I will update the answer, I don't have MYSQL installed so wasn't able to check.

And the date is a keyword in oracle but not sure in MYSQL so use it in quotes like "date".

Case 1:

```
SELECT dept_id, 
       AVG(cnt) average_emp 
FROM (SELECT dept_id, 
             days, 
             COUNT(emp_id) cnt
      FROM (SELECT dept_id, 
                   emp_id, 
                   SUM(logins) logins, 
                   to_char(DATES, 'dd') days
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE to_char(DATES,'mmyyyy') = '012018' 
            GROUP BY dept_id, 
                     emp_id, 
                     to_char(DATES, 'dd')          )
      WHERE logins > 0 
      GROUP BY dept_id, 
               days    )
GROUP BY dept_id;
```

Case 2:

```
SELECT dept_id, 
       COUNT(emp_id) 
FROM (SELECT dept_id, 
             emp_id, 
             SUM(logins) logins
      FROM mytable
      WHERE to_char(DATES,'mmyyyy') = '012018'
      GROUP BY dept_id, 
               emp_id      )
WHERE logins > 0 
GROUP BY dept_id;
```

Case 3:

```
SELECT months, 
       users,
       ROUND( (users - nvl(LAG(users) OVER (ORDER BY rownum),users) ) / nvl(LAG(users) OVER (ORDER BY ROWNUM), 1)
, 2) growth_rate
FROM (SELECT to_char(mt.DATES, 'MON-YYYY') months,
             count(mt.EMP_ID)              users
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM MYTABLE
            ORDER BY DATES) mt
      WHERE mt.DATES >= to_date('DEC-2017', 'MON-YYYY') 
        AND mt.DATES <= to_date('JAN-2018', 'MON-YYYY')
      GROUP BY to_char(mt.DATES, 'MON-YYYY')
      ORDER BY to_date(months, 'MON-YYYY')            ) oq
WHERE exists(SELECT 1 
             FROM MYTABLE iq
             WHERE to_char(iq.DATES, 'MON-YYYY') = oq.months
               AND iq.EMP_ID IN (SELECT EMP_ID 
                                 FROM MYTABLE 
                                 WHERE iq.LOGINS > 0)       );
```

Case 4:

```
SELECT dept_id, 
       emp_id 
FROM (SELECT dept_id, 
             emp_id
      FROM mytable
      WHERE to_char(DATES,'mmyyyy') = '122017' 
        AND logins > 0 
      GROUP BY dept_id, 
               emp_id      )
INTERSECT
SELECT dept_id, 
       emp_id 
FROM (SELECT dept_id, 
             emp_id
      FROM mytable
      WHERE to_char(DATES,'mmyyyy') = '012018' 
        AND logins > 0 
      GROUP BY dept_id, 
               emp_id     )
```

Case 5:

```
-- not full proof
SELECT COUNT(*) emp_cnt 
FROM (SELECT emp_id,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY DATES) rn,
             COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY DATES) cnt
      FROM mytable
      WHERE to_char(DATES,'mmyyyy') = '012018'
        AND logins > 0
      ORDER BY rn, 
               cnt      )
WHERE rn = cnt 
  AND rn >= 3;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12937828/aman-singh-rajpoot in 3 question we need to check the growth of users from the past month basically logic would be current month count - last month / last month counts

Comment: ok will try that also and also let me know for the other cases if it works, I don't have the database installed but the logic will be similar.